# Atlassian JWT Authentication Vulnerability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, jwt, confluence

I have a connect app in the Atlassian app marketplace that is failing the JWT authentication vulnerability scanner. Below is a sample of the vulnerability description from the [security scanner](https://github.com/atlassian-labs/connect-security-req-tester);

Vulnerability Description
The EcoScanner check, Authentication of Application Resources, for Connect Security Requirements Tester has reported the following issue:

> One or more endpoints returned a <400 status code without
> authentication information. This may indicate that your app is not
> performing authentication and authorization checks. JWT token used by
> the scanner is a fake JWT generated for testing purposes. Note: If you
> think authentication is absolutely not required on reported endpoints,
> please raise a review on the vulnerability ticket raised and Atlassian
> EcoAppSec team will take a look.

My app is a Ruby on Rails app. I have tried to create a method that checks for a valid jwt token in all post requests to my app. I then use this method in my webhook endpoints. Yet, that has not solved the jwt authentication vulnerability issue. How do I fix that ?

```
    def check_jwt(user)
      authorization_header = request.headers['Authorization']
    
      # Ensure the Authorization header exists and starts with "JWT "
      if authorization_header&.start_with?('JWT ')
        jwt_token = authorization_header[4..-1]
        shared_secret = user.shared_secret
    
        begin
          decoded_token = JWT.decode(jwt_token, shared_secret, true, algorithm: 'HS256')
          rescue JWT::DecodeError => e
          render json: { error: 'Unauthorized' }, status: :unauthorized
          raise e # Raise an exception to halt further execution
       end
    
       # Continue processing with the decoded token
       # ...
       else
         render json: { error: 'Unauthorized' }, status: :unauthorized
         raise JWT::DecodeError, 'Missing or invalid Authorization header'
       end    
     end
```

Comment: What happens if authorization_header is nil or does not start with JWT?

Comment: It raises an error as seen in the conditional statement.

 raise JWT::DecodeError, 'Missing or invalid Authorization header' @dbugger

Comment: Doesn't look like it -- please provide the whole method